# Query does not return results -- when using native query with sqlite

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I wrote the following method in repository

```
@Query(value = "delete from bin_values where id in (select bv.id from bin_values bv inner join bin b on bv.bin_id = b.id where b.stat_id = ?1)", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteByStatId(long statId);
```

unfortunately, when I run this function, the following error occurs:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract
>   ResultSet; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract
>   ResultSet
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
>   extract ResultSet
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query does not return results

Of course it has no results, since it is delete query. How to force it go?

Comment: Query methods that are likely to change the underlying data need to be [annotated with `@Modifying`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries).

Comment: Thanks, that helped!